# Trigger language change in Wordpress

Tags: multi-language

I have read this: http://blog-en.icanlocalize.com/installing-wordpress-for-multiple-language-blogs/how-to-localize-wordpress-themes-and-plugins-with-gettext/

Right now, I have qTranslate installed because I could not find a way to "Trigger" to switch to fr_FR. I use qTranslate to "switch" by using `http://mysite.com/page?lang=fr`

So, the question is, how do you "trigger" the switch to another language without manually doing the following: `define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');`?

Best Regards,
W

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I will work on this tomorrow. I see that "example 2" will probably work for me.