# Changing interface language without multisite

Tags: multi-language, localization, language

I want to change the Theme's interface language without making multisite by passing langauage parameter into the URL.

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url('/')?lang=bn ?>">Bengali</a>
```

My thought is to use the following code:

```
if(get_query_var('bn')) {

    /**
     * CHANGE THE 'WPLANG' IN wp-config.php TO bn_BD ON THEME SWITCHING
     * Thanks: toscho
     * Source: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/121136/22728
     * -------------------------------------------------- */

    add_filter( 'locale', 'toscho_change_language' );

    function toscho_change_language( $locale ) {
        return 'bn_BD';
    }

}
```

With checking `isset()` of the parameter in URL, loading of this code block. And using the theme's language file `bn_BD`.

But I'm actually curious about the logical proceedings:

- Is this concept Ok?
- Will it load the theme's language file successfully?

Comment: Don't use `get_query_var` for variables that are not *query* variables. Use: `toscho_change_language( $locale ) { $bn = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'bn' ) ? : $locale; }` no need of get_query_var, no need of isset, just one line effective function. Regarding the 2 questions, it seems ok to me, but to be honest locale is not a field where I'm expert.

Comment: Thanks @G.M. I answered in my way. Tried your one with a syntax error, saying unwanted bracket ({). Would love if you comment how I can make my answer with your code. With advance thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 notes regarding [your own answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149012/35541):

- try to not access on super global variables directly, but using [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)
- your code throw a notice if `$_GET['lang']` is not set

So your code can be improved:

```
function toscho_change_language() {
    return 'bn_BD';
}

if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'lang', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) === 'bn' ) {
  add_filter( 'locale', 'toscho_change_language' );
}
```

Or if your server has PHP 5.3+

```
if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'lang', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) === 'bn' ) {
  add_filter( 'locale', function() { return 'bn_BD'; } );
}
```

Finally, if you mind that in future you may want to support additional languages, you can write the function in a easily extensible way:

```
function gm_change_language( $locale ) {
    $langs = array(
       'bn' => 'bn_BD',
       'sw' => 'sw_TZ' // Tanzania Swahili 
    );
    $l = strtolower( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'lang', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
    return $l && array_key_exists( $l, $langs ) ? $langs[$l] : $locale; 
}

add_filter( 'locale', 'gm_change_language' );
```

Problem with this code is that clicking an inner link, language parameter is lost. A possible solution is to use a cookie to store the language.

I'll apply this improvement to last snippet, but can be used also in the previous.

```
function gm_change_language( $locale ) {
    $langs = array(
       'bn' => 'bn_BD',
       'sw' => 'sw_TZ' // Tanzania Swahili 
    );
    $l = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'lang', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( ! empty( $l ) ) {
       setcookie ( 'my_theme_lang', $l, 0 );
    } else {
       $l = filter_input( INPUT_COOKIE, 'my_theme_lang', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    }
    return $l && array_key_exists( $l, $langs ) ? $langs[$l] : $locale; 
}

add_filter( 'locale', 'gm_change_language' );
```

And sure, as you said, you need to [translate](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) your theme and load the texdomain using [`load_theme_textdomain`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain).

And, just a note for future readers, to be able to translate strings in a theme, all of them must be wrote using [i18n functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Translatable_strings).

Comment: Begging a little bit of help so that the code can be bullet-proof. The parameter's getting gone when any inner link is clicked (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18972502/1743124). So how can I pass the code into a WP Session, and get the session data back using this function?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam updated answer to use a cookie to store language.

Answer (score 0):

**Trigger in template:**

```
<a href="?lang=bn">BN</a>|<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">EN</a>
```

**Code in `functions.php`:**

```
function toscho_change_language( $locale ) {
    return 'bn_BD';
}

if( $_GET['lang'] && $_GET['lang'] == 'bn' ) add_filter( 'locale', 'toscho_change_language' );
```

To make my theme translation-ready:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'your-theme', get_template_directory() . '/lang' );
```

And I put my translation-file `bn_BD.po` (using **Poedit**) inside my theme's `lang` folder. And yala!